# Odoo 10 - Qweb align col-xs-n

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have a barcode inside a `<div class="col-xs-n">` element in Odoo 10 QWeb PDF report:

```xml
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('Code128', o.name, 600, 100)" style="width:300px;height:50px;"/>
</div>
```

Is there any class that could be applied to `<div>` element in order to horizontally center the barcode?

Comment: @Naglis how can I highlight the code. I do not forget to highlight, I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: Hey @M.E., no problem, see [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: you can add css style with that div

Comment: @burmese-pythis Feel free to suggest CSS code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bootstrap class *text-center* like below.

```
<div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
    <img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('Code128', o.name, 600, 100)" style="width:300px;height:50px;"/>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these classes..

There are native bootstrap classes available like:

```
class="text-center"
```

or

```
class="pagination-centered"
```